# Proving that “hypodescendance” is (or is not) illogical

Tags: social-epistemology, race

I’m really interested in social philosophy and analyzing the categories (and implied logic) of our social world. Clearly, “race” is a category with deep prospects for analysis.

I personally think that because of my cultural environment, I probably carry deeply embedded, subconscious “beliefs” (or, cognitive mechanisms structuring my perception of reality, rather) influenced by [hypodescendance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-drop_rule). A very common example of hypodescendance is that if someone is maybe even 25% “ethnically/genetically African” (which I also believe has deep definitional problems needing to be probed further into), they may be classified as “black/Black”.

Before I get into this, I want to discuss a principle of social epistemology I haven’t really verbalized before.

It seems like so many truth-claims / propositional claims about the social world are based on the validity of subjectively, interpretatively taking “an average”. So if I say, “it seems like in a lot of places nowadays, it’s implied that using/respecting someone’s preferred pronouns is very morally important”, it is actually really hard for me to definitively claim that. It requires me to take the mental average of lots of experiences I’ve had, and claim they have something in common. Because each situation is different (an argument I had with a stranger on the street, something I saw someone say on Twitter, a subtle change in wording I noticed on a form at the doctor’s office, noticing a new law being passed or discussed in some foreign country, and so on, and so on), I cannot really formulate what general law or phenomenon or tendency seems to be happening in society, without allowing myself to construct a verbal description that I think encompasses all of those specific cases, and what they imply. This sometimes leads to a terminology that comes off as vague - the “average” of say, Wikipedia rules’s explicitly ruling that articles are to be written exclusively using a person’s preferred pronouns, plus starting off a meeting by people sharing their preferred pronouns in a circle, plus other things, amounts to some generalization like, “Society seems to think that using preferred pronouns is morally important.”

I want to analyze that idea in its own right further. For now, I’ll just say that, all I can do is claim, based on memories and experiences I have had, that as I perceive it, there are ways in which “hypodescendance” is to an extent a social phenomenon present in our society. And as I said, this claim is a subjective “average” of a number of highly distinct things I am thinking of.

---

Let’s consider the claim that there is an asymmetry in how one may be classified between the two racial categories of “white” and “black”. Someone who is a little bit black, or partially black, is still black. It is less so for being white. Some people who are half black and half white may call themselves half white, but my subjective claim is this is less common. Blackness predominates over whiteness as a totalizing racial classification.

This is not just the case for asking people what they think the definition of black or white is. It is a diffuse “social force”, for lack of a better term. We might see, around us, that it is very common for people who are only partially “black” to still group together or be grouped together with people who are “fully black”, in social situations.

My question is, can we logically prove that there is no logical reason for this, or, are there any hypotheses about exactly why this happens, other than “latent hypodescendance” permeating our social world, influencing our very *perception*?

Here’s what I mean. If you have this hypodescendant ontological principle imprinted in your subconscious, it actually feels subjectively valid and *self-evident* that a half-black person is clearly of the category “black”; i.e., they look black. They look more black than they do white.

Someone might claim this is exactly like how cultures subdivide the color frequency spectrum into categories - a culture that doesn’t distinguish between blue and green may not merely perceive the difference but not have a word for it - they may, in a way hard to authentically imagine for those of us from outside the culture, not intuitively experience any categorical difference between blue and green. Obviously, they can discern the difference in shade, but it is possible (but uncertain) that their mind really is seeing “one thing”.

Those kinds of claims, like the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis, must be scrutinized. We do not know if they are true or not. We need deep ways to assess them.

So my question is, can it be logically proven that the subjective coherence I perceive in grouping half-black people with black people is 100% arbitrary, constructed by my subconscious; or is there a logical argument for why that classification has inherent motivation?

Could we imagine an alternative world where half black-half white people are perceived as, in terms of appearance, clearly on the “whiteness” spectrum, and there is an obvious categorical jump from a half black person to a fully black person? Or is there some reason why this is actually less likely to occur?

Comment: not my downvote, but fwiw i would read the question more gratefully if it was more concise. carry on...

Comment: The question has an obvious historical answer. It comes down to the fact that America is a racist and colorist country, and in the past there were only two or three race categories available on public documents, voting records, etc. Beyond that, as far as I know, in the Black community in the US in particular it is the case that people with pretty much any discernible recent Black ancestry and culture are considered as such. This also comes from racism and slavery, and I believe it is a unifying notion and practice for Black Americans regardless of their specific ancestry.